# Bubble sort in a Vector in Java

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm creating a program that can sort objects (vector) with the Bubble sort method. I found a code on the internet which helped me alot to create it (Bubble sort in Arrays):
http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-to-bubble-sort

When i compile the program i don't get any syntax error, but the results are not correct. I think i made an error in the IF-Statement, but i'm not sure if that's the only error. Here is the result i get when i run it:

```
Input number of integers to sort
5
Enter 5 integers
2
0
1
6
4
Sorted list of numbers
1
2
3
3
3
```

And here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class BubbleSortVector {
  public static void main(String []args) {
    int n, c, d, swap;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input number of integers to sort");
    n = in.nextInt();

    Vector v ;
    v = new Vector();

    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) 
      //v.addElement(c);
     v.insertElementAt(in.nextInt(),c);


    for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
      for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
        if ((Integer)v.elementAt(d) > (Integer)v.elementAt(d+1)) /* For descending order use < */

        {
          swap = (Integer)v.elementAt(d);
          v.insertElementAt(d+1,d);
          v.insertElementAt(swap,d+1);

        }
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Sorted list of numbers");

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) 
      System.out.println(v.elementAt(c));
  }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are using a Vector? Not that it matters in this case, just curious. In 99.9996 (I believe that to be the exact number) of the cases you do not want a `Vector` in most of those cases what you want is a `List` implementation, in this case I recommend an `ArrayList`. Again, not related to the error.

Comment: @Emz It's for my oral exam, i have to make one with arrays and another with vectors. And make a mini-presentation of it :)

Comment: Do you have access to a proper IDE that lets you set breakpoints for debugging?

Comment: @Coderchu i have tried it but i don't really see my error :/

Comment: I think I just picked it out, take a look at my answer. It's a bit confusing with your variable names ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    // ...
    Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<>();
    // ...
    for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++) {
        for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
            if (v.get(d) > v.get(d + 1)) {
                swap = v.get(d);
                v.set(d, v.get(d + 1));
                v.set(d + 1, swap);
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I just had to convert the objects into Integers:if ((Integer)v.get(d) > (Integer)v.get(d + 1)) { AND swap = (Integer)v.get(d);

Comment: @petie12 Then you are *still* using **raw types**. ***Please* don't** do that.

Comment: @petie12, please do not cast them as Integer, instead follow Elliott's answer and tell what objects the `Vector v` stores.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch why did you delete your own answer?

Comment: This is not Bubble Sort though.

Answer (score 0):

Your following code is wrong, inserting `d+1` at index `d` means you're using the value of the loop index/counter into the vector, not the actual value that is at `d+1`

```
swap = (Integer)v.elementAt(d);
v.insertElementAt(d+1,d);    // this is incorrect, d is the index/loop counter
v.insertElementAt(swap,d+1);
```

Chage that middle line to:

```
v.insertElement((Integer)v.elementAt(d+1), d);
```

Comment: I changed it but when i input the same numbers as the one from above, i get 0 0 2 2 0 instead of 0 1 2 4 6

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by simple swapping method. after loop you print the array.

```
        int[] Array = new int[5]{2 , 0 , 6 , 1 , 4};

        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Array.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (Array[j] > Array[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = Array[j + 1];
                    Array[j + 1] = Array[j];
                    Array[j] = temp;
                }
            }             
        }
```